# Strange behavior for inline-block in different browsers

Tags: html, css

I need help to explain the `display: inline-block` behaviour between different browsers.

I am working with a Masonry template, it works well but I am seeing a weird behaviour between Firefox and Chrome.

In Chrome the div `.masonry` shows extra empty space at the bottom

[image: chrome_image]

In Firefox the div `.masonry` adjusts itself to fit the content of the current cards.

[image: firefox_image]

I am not able to adjust the extra space at the bottom in Chrome in the same way it works for Firefox, the div should grow or shrink depending on the card contents, is there a way to fix this?

This is the JSFiddle for your reference https://jsfiddle.net/gb4av2eq/

Comment: Your browser view area is taller in one than in the other. The first screenshot is 923px in height and the second is 798px. The tiles occupy about the same area but the remaining, empty view area is different because of how you've sized your browser windows.

Comment: @Ouroborus yeah, its my fault for not taking the picture without zoom. I wanted to show the complete page. But if I put both browsers side by side you can see that the browser window size does not affect the outcome. https://imgur.com/a/TA6SreJ

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Looks like there's an issue with how [`columns`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns) works in Chrome. Not sure that there's a fix for it.